# Bool variable. Logic of the check

Tags: c++, boolean-logic

So I have a question about `bool` variables.

This is a program which checks whether the due is payed on time and if it is not, it is multiplied by 1.10.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    float Dues;
    cout<<"Enter ammount: \n";
    cin>>Dues;
    cout<<"On time? (y/n)";
    char yn;
    cin>>yn;
    bool Overdue = yn !="y"; //TRUE (1) if it is late, FALSE (0) if it is on time
    float AmountDue;
    AmountDue = Overdue ? Dues*1.10 : Dues;
    cout<<"Ammount due: ";
    cout<<<<AmountDue;
    return 0;

}
```

I don't undestand the logic of the bool

We have

`bool Overdue = yn !="y";`

Now this is ***my understaning*** of the logic of the bool and it is ***NOT right***

If "n" is entered => N is NOT Y which is CORRECT therefore the bool is true => 1

If "y" is entered => Y is NOT Y which is WRONG, therefore fasle => 0

But it is actually the other way around and I can't explain it logically to myself.
On what logic is based `bool Overdue = yn !="y";` ?

Comment: `bool Overdue = yn !='y';`

Comment: That's the worst spell of *weather* I've ever seen! :) (try *whether*)

Comment: lol I am writing completely different word :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to jrok's answer the problem you are encountering is that you *assume* that lowercase and uppercase characters are the same thing. They are *NOT*. 'y' and 'Y' are two different characters. Same thing for 'n' and 'N'.

You write:

> If "n" is entered => N is NOT Y which is CORRECT therefore the bool is
>   true => 1

No. 'n' is not 'y'.

> If "y" is entered => Y is NOT Y which is WRONG, therefore fasle => 0

It's CORRECT. 'y' is NOT 'Y'.

Try this instead:

```
bool Overdue = (yn != 'n') && (yn != 'N');
```

Comment: Ah, +1, it didn't occur to me this could confuse OP.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for unexpected behaviour is that you're comparing a `char` with a string literal `"y"`. String literals are of type `const char[n]` where `n` is the length of the literal including the terminating NUL character.

Compare with a character literal instead:

`yn != 'y'`

When you say this: `yn != "y"`, the char gets promoted to `int` and the string literal decays to `const char*`. How is this supposed to behave is unspecified by the standard.

The result of the expression gets stored in `bool Overdue`. When `yn` holds `'n'`, the expression is `true` ('n' is indeed different than 'y') so `true` will be stored, and vice versa).

Comment: Okay I corrected it, but I don't understand why N is 0 and Y is 1

Comment: And according to my logic it should be N - 1 and Y - 0

Comment: I don't see any 1s or 0s in your code. do you mean true and false?

Comment: After you change to char literal, your program behaves correctly, AFAICT.

Comment: Yes, 1 is true and 0 is false

Comment: @user1888353 Umm, with the type correction suggested by jrok (that is, as the question stands now), it works as it should (entering 'n' makes `overdue` have value `true`).

Comment: @user1888353 In C++, `bool` is an actual type and `true` and `false` are its values. While they convert to 1 and 0 when converted to a number, it's better to think about them as boolean values, not as numbers.

Comment: Now this program is from a book I read, and if I have to write a bool variable I would not understand how to write it correctly, just because I don't know how to set it TRUE or FALSE

Comment: Its confusing me the fact that Y != Y is actually TRUE ??? How's that working out? Y is Y ... Y = Y ...  Y is not Y is TRUE nosence :D

Comment: It's not. When you enter 'y', the expression `yn != 'y'` becomes `'y' != 'y'`, which clearly isn't true - the result of expression is `false` and that's what ends up stored in `Overdue`. Try again and see for yourself.

Comment: @user1888353 `true` and `false` are keywords of the language. Declaring a boolean variable and setting it to `true` is simply `bool myVar = true;`

Comment: The problem is that he enters Y. He assumes that upper and lowercase characters are the same thing.